# Restart absolute position for jQuery animation loop

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

## What I have:

An absolutely positioned image of a plane that moves across and off the screen.

## What I need:

I need the animation to loop/restart every 10 seconds i.e. the plane just appears in its default absolute position at the beginning of each loop.

## The problem:

I've tried numerous examples but the closest I can get is using [this](http://www.sk89q.com/2011/07/looping-jquery-animations-indefinately/) example using .queue and .callee. It loops, but requires a reverse animation to reposition the image. Instead, I need the image to reposition without animating.

## My code:

The CSS the animation starts with (and needs to restart with for each loop)...

```
<style>
#main_content_container{
width:800px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
height:2000px;
}

#sprite_plane{
    position:absolute;
    left:-400px;
    top:400px;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
</style>
```

The jQuery animation...

```
<script>

  $("#sprite_plane").animate({
    opacity: 1,
    "left": "+=430px",
    "top": "-=530px",
  }, 1500 );

</script>
```

The HTML...

```
<div id="main_content_container">
    <img src="images/plane.png" alt="" width="120" height="120" id="sprite_plane" />
</div>
```

Comment: Any ideas why this question was down-voted? How can I improve it?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Could you please add a screenshot or some preview of what you are trying to do and what you wanna achieve?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I've uploaded a demonstration for you (http://dominornovus.com/jq-ani-demo/index.html). Refresh the page to repeat animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this recursive function should do what you want

```
function loopAnimation(doReset) {
    var $el = $("#sprite_plane");
    if (doReset) {
       $el.css({ left: "-=430px", top: "+=530px", opacity:0 });/*assume opacity is zero at start*/
    }
    $el.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        "left": "+=430px",
        "top": "-=530px",
    }, 1500, function() {

        setTimeout(function() {
            loopAnimation(true);
        }, 10000);
    });
}
```

In page initialization code call:

```
 loopAnimation(false);
```

After that the complete callback of each instance of animation will  call the function within a `setTimeout`

Comment: Fantastic. Works perfectly, thanks. loopAnimation is called three times. loopAnimation(doReset) makes sense to me because you're saying if foo exists do bar which creates the loop. I don't however understand how your loopAnimation function behaves with true and false. Why is `loopAnimation(false)` necessary on initialization? What is `loopAnimation(true)` actually telling `loopAnimation()` to do? Does the true = execute/run?

Comment: Since your code uses incremental positioning I didn't know if start posiiton is `top:0,left:0` so on first run, I couldn't set the element to it's intial position. Thus I put an `if` so when you call the function on start up, it doesn't do the position reset. The argument in the function, and the `if` could be removed if you want to set the reset css to absolute values and then reset could occur on first run